# Why are these characters coming up in Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

Also the html isn't rendering.  Doesn't happen on firefox or ie, who knows what other browsers it does happen on.  As you can see the content type is right, I'm guessing it might have to do with the way the file is being saved, since it's a static html file without an html extension?  But I don't know how to fix it. Anyone know how?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It displays like this because it was saved as `unicode` encoding. Make sure you're setting the encoding type to `ASCII` when you save the file, and this will go away.